# WAMP 2.2e - phpmyadmin Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, wamp

All services are running (wamp icon is green) by when I try to turn on phpmyadmin I get this error. What seems to be a problem?

Comment: Open php.ini find and edit values of `max_execution_time` & `max_input_time` then restart WAMP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set set max execution time like @HanhNghien said in the comment with in your **php.ini**.

```
max_execution_time = 120
max_input_time = 120
```

But i think the better question is why need phpmyadmin so much time. Perhaps you should check your apache logs and check if there are some errors.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this with the variables section in phpmyadmin by setting an insanely high number to the timeout.  It wouldn't accept '0'.